# Validate String(query) to see if column names contain SQL functions

Tags: java, sql, regex, string, stringtokenizer

I have hundreds of database queries like below format

```
select VERSION, INSTALL_TIME from M_DATABASE_HISTORY
```

I use regex as below to get the column names, (it tokenises the string between SELECT and FROM based on (,)comma )

```
String[] columnNames= query.split(" [fF][rR][oO][mM] ")[0]
                           .split("[ ]*[sS][eE][lL][eE][cC][tT] ")[1]
                           .split("[ ]*,[ ]*");
```

This code works fine for the above queries.

However, **I am having problem to get column name when I have used a function in column names** like MAP below and it returning me 8 column names when there are 4 columns

```
select A.SYSTEM_ID, DATABASE_NAME, HOST, MAP(VALID, 'TRUE', 'Active' , 'FALSE' , 'Inactive')  AS Current_Status  from M_LICENSE A, M_DATABASE B where A.SYSTEM_ID = B.SYSTEM_ID
```

Output i am getting

```
0.]A.SYSTEM_ID
1.]DATABASE_NAME
2.]HOST
3.]MAP(VALID
4.]'TRUE'
5.]'Active'
6.]'FALSE'
7.]'Inactive')  AS Current_Status
```

Expected output

```
0.]A.SYSTEM_ID
1.]DATABASE_NAME
2.]HOST
3.]MAP(VALID,'TRUE','Active','FALSE','Inactive')  AS Current_Status 
OR
3.] Current_Status
```

Can anyone please help me to build a regex for this?
Or any better approach is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What text pattern do you want to match? What is your exact expected output for the 2 sample inputs you supplied?

Comment: I just want to get `column name or alias name` if present. there are functions like MAP(...) and ROUND(...) used in my queries

Comment: @Wiktor Stribizew any idea on this?

Comment: Sorry, I am traveling and have only mobile Internet access. Really, this is a too broad topic for a quick regex solution. You have the testing data, we don't.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribizew okay. thanks for the reply. Once you get time could you please go through the `solution` below i have come up with? It is an java main prg. pls guide me how i can do it better

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a function to validate my Columnnames for function names. If my columnName contain a '(' bracket I appeneded the next columns until i found a ')' bracket.

Code Snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String[] queries = {
            "select A.SYSTEM_ID, DATABASE_NAME, HOST, START_TIME, VERSION, HARDWARE_KEY, "
                    + "INSTALL_NO, SYSTEM_NO, PRODUCT_NAME, PRODUCT_LIMIT, PRODUCT_USAGE, START_DATE, EXPIRATION_DATE, "
                    + "LAST_SUCCESSFUL_CHECK, MAP(PERMANENT, 'TRUE', 'Yes' , 'FALSE' , 'No') PERMANENT, "
                    + "MAP(VALID, 'TRUE', 'Active' , 'FALSE' , 'Inactive')  AS Current_Status  from M_LICENSE A, "
                    + "M_DATABASE B where A.SYSTEM_ID = B.SYSTEM_ID",
            "SELECT 'USER' TYPE, TABLE_TYPE, count(1) VAL FROM SYS.M_TABLES WHERE SCHEMA_NAME IN (SELECT SCHEMA_NAME from SYS.SCHEMAS WHERE SCHEMA_OWNER NOT IN ('SYS','_SYS_REPO','SYSTEM','_SYS_AFL','SAPHSA','SAPHEA','_SYS_EPM','_SYS_STATISTICS')) GROUP BY TABLE_TYPE UNION SELECT 'USER' TYPE, 'TOTAL', count(1) VAL FROM SYS.M_TABLES WHERE SCHEMA_NAME IN (SELECT SCHEMA_NAME from SYS.SCHEMAS WHERE SCHEMA_OWNER NOT IN ('SYS','_SYS_REPO','SYSTEM','_SYS_AFL','SAPHSA','SAPHEA','_SYS_EPM','_SYS_STATISTICS')) UNION SELECT 'SYSTEM' TYPE, TABLE_TYPE, count(1) VAL FROM SYS.M_TABLES WHERE SCHEMA_NAME IN (SELECT SCHEMA_NAME from SYS.SCHEMAS WHERE SCHEMA_OWNER IN ('SYS','_SYS_REPO','SYSTEM','_SYS_AFL','SAPHSA','SAPHEA','_SYS_EPM','_SYS_STATISTICS')) GROUP BY TABLE_TYPE UNION SELECT 'SYSTEM' TYPE, 'TOTAL', count(1) VAL FROM SYS.M_TABLES WHERE SCHEMA_NAME IN (SELECT SCHEMA_NAME from SYS.SCHEMAS WHERE SCHEMA_OWNER IN ('SYS','_SYS_REPO','SYSTEM','_SYS_AFL','SAPHSA','SAPHEA','_SYS_EPM','_SYS_STATISTICS'))" };

    for (int x = 0; x < queries.length; x++) {

        String query = queries[x];

        String[] fields = query.split(" [fF][rR][oO][mM] ")[0].split("[ ]*[sS][eE][lL][eE][cC][tT] ")[1]
                .split("[ ]*,[ ]*");

        fields = validateColumnNames(fields);

        for (int my = 0; my < fields.length; my++) {
            System.out.println(my + ".]" + fields[my]);
        }
    }

}

//validator for column Names to check function. If my columnName contain a 
// '(' bracket I appeneded the next columns until i found a ')' bracket.
private static String[] validateColumnNames(String[] fields) {
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean enter = false;
    String appendField = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        String onefield = fields[i];

        if (!enter) {
            if (onefield.contains("(")) {
                appendField = onefield;
                enter = true;
            } else {
                result.add(onefield);
            }
        } else {
            if (onefield.contains(")")) {
                appendField = appendField + "," + onefield;
                result.add(appendField);
                enter = false;
                appendField = "";
            } else {
                appendField = appendField + "," + onefield;
            }
        }
    }
    String[] validColNames = new String[result.size()];
    validColNames = result.toArray(validColNames);

    return validColNames;
}
```

Comment: if anyone has a better answer please provide?